pkg_check_modules IMPORTED_TARGET do not get propagated
I know similar questions have been posted, but I have this issue and I haven't been able to solve it. Here is my use case:
add_library(targetA ...)
pkg_check_modules(GST REQUIRED IMPORTED_TARGET GLOBAL gstreamer-base-1.0)
target_link_libraries(targetA PRIVATE PkgConfig::GST)

According to this answer, this is the correct way using pkg_check_modules. However, the above code snippet fails when I try to build an executable with: ...undefined reference to gst_base_sink_get_type and I am guessing it is telling that the targetA does not link against gstreamer-base-1.0 (or more accurately not linking against the gstbase-1.0 library)
If I however go with:
add_library(targetA ...)
pkg_check_modules(GST REQUIRED gstreamer-base-1.0)
target_link_libraries(targetA PRIVATE ${GST_LINK_LIBRARIES})

everything works. However, this also leads that my targetA Targets.cmake file is polluted with build host paths, so if someone else is using the targetA Targets.cmake on his build host, it fails, as it contains paths from my host.
Any thoughts what I might be doing wrong here? Thanks.

"the above code snippet fails when I try to build an executable" - How exactly you use library when build the executable? If you use CMake for build the executable, then show relevant CMake code.

Thanks for the quick reply and I'm sorry it took me this long to reply, I've been busy with other stuff and with the issue above. Apparently, I've been missing some gstreamer libs and adding them solved the problem. I'll edit the answer
